# Is it a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas

**"I hadn't any idea about the vast application of programming language until I knew about it, joining online programming courses."**

-- is it a correct sentence? I am especially worried whether I should use the comma before " joining online..." section.

I wanted to express in one sentence that I have learned about the vast application of programming language joining online programming courses and I had no prior idea about it.

May I also write in the following manner? -

**"I hadn't any idea about the vast application of programming language until joining online programming courses, I knew about it."**

Comment: I would like to know if my sentence grammatically correct? Along with that, I am confused how should I use the comma here.

Comment: Your second sentence sounds much better—except for the fact that it doesn't stop at *programming courses*. I would use it, but remove *I knew about it*  altogether.

Comment: @HankyPanky There's nothing at all wrong with *I hadn't any idea*.